# openstack cinder VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota tips mismatch volume type

Tags: openstack, quota, ceph, cinder

Create a volume will show the same error tips, no matter what `--type` option with.

```
# openstack volume create --size 500 test_vol
VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota: Requested volume or snapshot exceeds allowed gigabytes quota.
 Requested 500G, quota is 965362G and 965362G has been consumed.

# openstack volume create --size 500 --type ceph_ssd test_vol_ssd
VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota: Requested volume or snapshot exceeds allowed gigabytes quota.
 Requested 500G, quota is 965362G and 965362G has been consumed.

# openstack quota show
| Field                 | Value   |
| gigabytes             | 965362  |
| gigabytes___DEFAULT__ | -1      |
| gigabytes_ceph_ssd    | 9965362 |
```

In sometime, while create a `ceph_ssd` volume type, it will tips that **gigabytes_ceph_ssd** quota exceeds. Like this:

```
# openstack volume create --size 500 --type ceph_ssd test_vol_ssd
VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota: Requested volume or snapshot exceeds allowed gigabytes_ceph_ssd quota.
```

What's wrong with that? How could I solve this question? Anything was misunderstand by me?

Answer (score 0):

Shame of my ignorance.

**[gigabytes](https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/cli/cli-cinder-quotas.html)** means `Volume gigabytes allowed for each project`.

It will check whether **[exception.OverQuota](https://github.com/openstack/cinder/blob/master/cinder/volume/api.py#L1610)** for creating new volume previously. First will check the **gigabytes** for all volume capacity, and then the **gigabytes_specify_volume_type** while create volume with `--type` option.

Verify in develop environment:

```
$ openstack volume create --size 10 --type ceph_ssd test_vol4
VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota: ... gigabytes_ceph_ssd quota. Requested 10G, quota is 16753G and 16745G has been consumed.

$ openstack volume create --size 100 test_vol4
VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota: ... gigabytes quota. Requested 100G, quota is 1280970G and 1280951G has been consumed.

### created success, consumed will add +8G in gigabytes
$ openstack volume create --size 8 --type ceph_ssd test_vol4
$ openstack volume create --size 100 test_vol4
VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota: ... gigabytes quota. Requested 100G, quota is 1280970G and 1280959G has been consumed.

### check quota pass by gigabytes default by not gigabytes_ceph_ssd
$ openstack volume create --size 11 --type ceph_ssd test_vol4
VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota: ... gigabytes_ceph_ssd quota. Requested 11G, quota is 16753G and 16753G has been consumed.

### check quota not pass by gigabytes default
$ openstack volume create --size 12 --type ceph_ssd test_vol4
VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota: ... gigabytes quota. Requested 12G, quota is 1280970G and 1280959G has been consumed.

### without limit by gigabytes default quota
$ openstack quota set --gigabytes -1 proj_name
$ openstack volume create --size 12 --type ceph_ssd test_vol4
VolumeSizeExceedsAvailableQuota: ... gigabytes_ceph_ssd quota. Requested 12G, quota is 16753G and 16753G has been consumed.

### according to the CapacityWeigher, it will distribute the volume to ceph_ssd backend without specify volume type
### we have two backend ceph pool: ceph_hdd(capacity smaller than the other), ceph_ssd
### it will no check the quota of gigabytes_ceph_ssd, bcz create without --type option
$ openstack volume create --size 100 test_vol5
$ openstack volume show test_vol5
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                          | Value                                |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| name                           | test_vol5                            |
| os-vol-host-attr:host          | node-2@ceph_ssd#ceph_ssd             |
| size                           | 100                                  |
| status                         | available                            |
| type                           | __DEFAULT__                          |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```